# Test WCF with JSON Response

Tags: c#, json, wcf, http-status-code-404, http-error

I have a WCF Service that return a json. I want to test it using Fiddle (this is the application that is used in the tutorial i was following). The problem is that i get HTTP 404 error when invoking "AddAngajat" for example.

Implementation of the service :

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single, AddressFilterMode=AddressFilterMode.Any)]
    public class AngajatService : InterfaceAngajat
    {
        List<Angajat> listaAngajati =null;

        public AngajatService()
        {
            if (listaAngajati == null)
                listaAngajati = new List<Angajat>();
        }

        [WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate = "AddAngajat", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public void AddAngajat(Angajat angajat)
        {
            listaAngajati.Add(angajat);
        }
        public Angajat[] GetAllAngajati()
        {
            listaAngajati.Add(new Angajat() { idAngajat = "2f34", nume = "nume1" });
            return listaAngajati.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

App.config :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="testJSON.AngajatService">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="JSONEndpointBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="testJSON.InterfaceAngajat" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/testJSON/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="JSONEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any idea on how to fix this ? Other way of testing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `http://localhost:8732/testJSON/json/AddAngajat` and it should work.

Otherwise include your client code (or a snippet).

## UPDATE

With the changes you mentioned, URL must be this `http://localhost/testJSON/Service.svc/json/AddAngajat`

Comment: i use Fiddler as client. My service is now hosted by local IIS so i deleted the port from the url. http://localhost/testJSON/Service.svc returnes  ok, but how can i send a post request and how do i send the parameters ?

Comment: is working.....thanks a lot. I am a very noob begginer in C# and widnows services, so i don't know if is a soap or rest service. i will try to learn more. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Your request from fiddler would look something like below:

```
POST http://localhost/VirtualDirectoryName/testJson/service.svc/json/Addangajat HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 47

{"Id":6,"StringValue":"from client rajeshwin7"}
```

Assuming your structure for the object "Angajat" is having 2 properties Id and StringValue.

Am not sure if you can perform a GET/POST call to a service that is hosted on Cassini from fiddler. I would rather host it in IIS and then use fiddler to invoke the service. If you dont want to host in IIS then use a .NET client with HttpWebRequest to invoke the rest service.

Comment: My service is hosted in IIS on my local machine. If i call http://localhost/testJSON/Service.svc/json/GetAllAngajati from my browser i get "Method not allowed." as response. From Fiddler i am trying : POST + http://localhost/testJSON/Service.svc/web/AddAngajat + HTTP/1.1 and i am sending {
"idAngajat":"angajat1",
"nume":"nume1"
}   Request headers : User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 41

   I still get 404.